# how to click link and then lose focus jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am appending some links to a div. What I am trying to do is when someone clicks on any of that link then the page should navigate to that link otherwise when clicked anywhere else those links should disappear.(A search box with suggestion to be exact.)

Base div:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-10">
     <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search-box">
</div>
```

Jquery to append links:

```
result_query = ''
$.each(search_result, function(i, item) {
    result_query = result_query + '<a href="/search/' + search_result[i][0] + '"><div class="suggestion-box"><img src="' + search_result[i][2] + '" style="height: 70px; width: 70px; margin: 5px;">' + search_result[i][1] + '</div></a>';
});
$('#search-box').after(result_query);
```

Jquery to remove links:

```
$(document).on('blur', '#search-box', function(event) {
    $('.suggestion-box').remove();
});
```

Now when i click on link it removes all the links and does not navigate page to the respective link. I want it to navigate to that clicked link instead of removing all links. how to correct the problem?

EDIT:  Added the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u32s4zqw/)

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle or Plunker demo?

Comment: @cst1992 i added a link for fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (imo) to do this is creating a holder `.suggestion-box`. In that box you could append your suggestions links:

```
success: function (data) {
    $(".suggestion-box").append(data);
}
```

Now all the links are appended to the holder. When clicking on a link you can navigate away. When clicking elsewhere, the suggestion box will fade out if you use below code (not tested though).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function() {
        $(".suggestion-box").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Maybe you might need to use `e.stopPropagation` or `e.preventDefault`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable-item").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: I added a js fiddle link. Might help you better understand the problem.